# Save socket for each user in node.js

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, socket.io

I am creating an application which uses socket.IO and node.js

Currently I am saving in a var (connections = {object}) in my application all the online sockets, so that I can target the right contents to users if they are online and store that data in my database if targeted users are offline.

Is this approach ok? Can I store in a var as many sockets as I want? Which are other approaches? Thank you

Comment: Why "you" need to store sockets? Can't you access it using `io.sockets`? It will give you all connected clients.

Comment: Yes but I need to know each clients which user is related to!

Comment: So I can target each content to the right user @Салман

Comment: I am not very sure about the approach, however, you can surely store sockets in a variable. Because its just a reference to those objects.

Comment: you can add unique id to your socket and access it through io.sockets